# Where can I find a beta reader for grammatical issues?

Tags: short-story, grammar, criticism, beta-readers

I’m looking forward to finding a beta reader to help getting me past my grammatical inaccuracies during my attempts at writing short stories.

I’m not a native English speaker, so I found myself lacking knowledge in regards to grammatical rules and usage of slang terms. I also have a rather limited vocabulary range.

I don’t aim at becoming a professional writer; in fact, my major concern is my ability to become more and more proficient in English written communication. 
In order to try to improve my writing skills, I challenged myself to  daily write short stories (kind of flash fiction pieces) 1,000 words tops.

So does anyone know where can I search for such beta reader or critique fellow?

Comment: I'd like to cooperate with you, find me in VK or Facebook by my name Alexander Listopadov and age 31 years. Russia, Krasnodar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try the free versions of Language Tool, Grammarly and ProWriting Aid. I use these all the time because they pick up many more problems than Microsoft Office.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you skip the beta-readers if you're going to give them a rough draft. Beta-readers are meant for close to final drafts and their purpose is to catch anything that you didn't catch before publication, as well as feedback on the story. I'll recommend that you subscribe to Microsoft Office 365. It's about 6.99 a month and then you can select under PROOFING in the Options Menu, "GRAMMAR AND REFINEMENTS." Make sure all the GRAMMAR choices are selected and you can select anything useful for the refinements. Word does a great job at finding any grammatical errors, but you also need to read your work aloud to yourself to make sure things flow and make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when it comes to people critiquing your work, any critique site will do (like Critique Circle), but you really should let them know you're interested in grammar checks, and not a substantive critique of your work.

That said: I wouldn't say this is the absolute best way to become better in English. Not when you don't enjoy writing (it sounds like that considering you have to force yourself everyday). I'd suggest picking up a few books and reading them. Not only do you learn a lot about English syntax, but you can expand your vocabulary. The very best way to read if you have this goal is to buy a kindle and read there, as then you can on the same device, in the middle of your reading, check out word definitions and whatnot. Also, Youtube is a great resource for learning grammar.

From one ESL writer to another ;)